# Enable touch feature in product images slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product image slider.

You can go to the next slide using the side circles.
[image]

I want to click on the photo to go to the next slide. And this feature can also be supported on mobile.

My JavaScript code :

```
function controls() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('button').removeClass('selected');
    $('.slideDiv1000').animate({
      top: -$('.container1000').height() * $(this).index()
    }, 450);
}

/***Event Listeners***/
const runCode = () => {
    const button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
    if ( button ) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < button.length; i++ ) {                     
        button[i].addEventListener('click', controls, false);
      }
    }
}

runCode();
```

Comment: On mobile, ```click``` basically becomes touch. If you don't need movement or special cases, just add an event listener with ```controls()``` on the click of an image.
If that doesn't work (maybe on some devices), use touch event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: If the `touchstart,touchend,touchcancel,touchmove` seem complicated, I suggest using `hammer.js`, which will also help you implement gestures in desktops (good UX).